# Expressing the sum of a scalar and vector multiplication in matrix form

Tags: vector

I have the following configuration:

Vector $\beta = (\beta_1, \beta_2,...,\beta_m)^T \in \mathbb{R}^m$

Lets rewrite $\beta = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\theta_j\phi_j$

where $\theta = (\theta_1,\theta_2,...,\theta_n)^T \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\phi_j = (\phi_{j1}, \phi_{j2},...,\phi_{jm})^T \in \mathbb{R}^m$

How do I express $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\theta_j\phi_j$ in matrix form so that $||\beta||_2^2 = \theta^TA\theta$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$?

So far I have only been able the express the sum in this matrix form:

$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\theta_j\phi_j = \begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\theta_j\phi_{j1} \\
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\theta_j\phi_{j2} \\
... \\
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\theta_j\phi_{jm} \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the $m \times n$ matrix by juxtaposing $\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_n$ column-wisely as follows:
\begin{align*}
\Phi = \begin{bmatrix}
\phi_1 & \phi_2 & \cdots & \phi_n
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align*}
it then follows by the definition of $\beta$ that $\beta = \Phi\theta$.  Now it should be evident that
\begin{align*}
\|\beta\|^2 = \beta^\top\beta = \theta^\top\Phi^\top\Phi\theta, 
\end{align*}
namely, the matrix $A$ you are looking for is $A = \Phi^\top\Phi$.

Comment: Brilliant! thank you very much for your answer. Don't know why I haven't thought of stacking the column vectors together...